# Show message when JTextField content is not equal to a certain int

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am figuring out how to show up a message-dialog-box whenever the user doesn't type the number 7 in a JTextField:

[image]

This is the code I am trying in the button click event:

```
    try {
        Double user_input = Double.parseDouble(myTextField.getText());
         while (user_input !=7) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type number 7","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an Event listener to the button worked for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    {  
        final JFrame f= new JFrame("TextField Example");  
        final JTextField textField;  
        textField=new JTextField("");  
        textField.setBounds(50,150, 200,30);  
        f.add(textField);  
        f.setSize(400,400);  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true); 
        JButton b=new JButton("Click Here");  
        b.setBounds(50,100,95,30);  
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                if(value!=7) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Number should be 7.","Dialog",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                
            }
        });
        f.add(b);  
        f.setSize(400,400);  
        f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setVisible(true);   
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but would be a better answer if it explained why HOTOMOL’s loop will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. It works if I type in the `JTextField` with numbers that are not 7. If I type letters, the pop-up warning will not show. I assume that it did not work when you typed letters, not numbers.

Here is the thing: `try ... catch` block is use to catch `exception`. If you type numbers, `double.parseDouble` will work, so there will be no `exception` in the `try` block to be catched, and you see the warning message if the condition in the `while` not met.

If you type letters, the `double.parseDouble` will throws exception because converting letters to double is not allowed. Instead of moving to next line (the while loop), it will jump to the `catch` block to handle the exception, but you do not specify how to do that, and you will not see any the warning message.

So, the solution is simple: add an action to `catch` block to do something when the `double.parseDouble` throws an exception, like showing a message:

```
try
{
    Double user_input = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    while (user_input != 7)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type number 7", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    break;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type numbers", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

You may notice that by using `while` the warning message keeps showing because the condition always `true` with the input not 7. So change to `if` as @Hades answer or add `break` to make it show 1 time only.

I prefer `if`.